# Shibboleth opensaml::FatalProfileException

Tags: shibboleth

I am implementing shibboleth IDP and SP. I have installed in my machine and tested it with testshib.org , both(IDP&SP) are working fine.

I am trying to use my own IDP with my SP.

Once I access the protected resource, SP redirects to the IDP login page correctly, after authentication is successful, it is redirected to the SP with the SAML encrypted response (With the servlet status code 500)  Which shows the following error ,

"opensaml::FatalProfileException at (https://myip.address/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST)
A valid authentication statement was not found in the incoming message."

I checked the native log which shows the following message.

"2013-08-29 20:22:36 ERROR Shibboleth.Listener [28868] shib_handler: remoted message returned an error: A valid authentication statement was not found in the incoming message.

2013-08-29 20:22:36 ERROR Shibboleth.Apache [28868] shib_handler: A valid authentication statement was not found in the incoming message."

How can I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What do the IdP logs show for the corresponding authentication attempt? You may need to elevate the log levels to DEBUG for IdP, OpenSAML and/or LDAP (conf/logging.xml) to get sufficiently descriptive results.